# Need to update data if it is present otherwisew insert in symfony/doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, backend

Below code is working properly. It is for inserting new record into the database.

Entity:-(`FileUpload.php`)

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/** 
 * @ORM\Entity 
 * @ORM\Table(name="FileUpload") 
 */
class FileUpload
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string",unique=true)
     */
    private $countryCode;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(type = "string") 
     */
    private $fileData;



    public function __construct(
        string $countryCode,
        string $fileData
    ) {
        $this->countryCode = $countryCode;
        $this->fileData = $fileData;
    }

    /** 
     * Get id 
     * 
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param integer $id
     */
    public function setId(int $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /** 
     * Set countryCode 
     * 
     * @param string $countryCode 
     * 
     * @return FileUpload 
     */

    public function setCountryCode($countryCode)
    {
        $this->countryCode = $countryCode;
        return $this;
    }

    /** 
     * Get countryCode 
     * 
     * @return string 
     */

    public function getCountryCode()
    {
        return $this->countryCode;
    }

    /**
     * Set fileData 
     * 
     * @param string $fileData
     * 
     * @return FileUpload 
     */

    public function setFileData($fileData)
    {
        $this->fileData = $fileData;
        return $this;
    }

    /** 
     * Get fileData 
     * 
     * @return string 
     */

    public function getFileData()
    {
        return $this->fileData;
    }
}
```

Controller:-

```
 /**
     * @Route("/file_upload")
     * @Method({"POST"})
     * @return JsonResponse
     */
    public function addAction(SubscriptorService $subscriptorService,  Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $countryCode = $request->request->get('countryCode');
        $fileData = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        $rst = $subscriptorService->fileUpload(
            $countryCode,
            $fileData
        );
        return new JsonResponse($rst);
    }
}
```

Service:-

```
/**
     * @param string $countryCode,
     * @param string $fileData
     */
    public function fileUpload(
        string $countryCode,
        string $fileData

    ): bool 
    {
        $program = new FileUpload($countryCode, $fileData);
        $this->em->persist($program);
        $this->em->flush();
        return true;
    }
```

But now I need to check. If `countryCode` is alredy present then I need to update the `fileData` corresponding to that `countryCode` .Else we need to insert new record.
so I modified service method.

```
/**
     * @param string $countryCode,
     * @param string $fileData
     */
    public function fileUpload(
        string $countryCode,
        string $fileData

    ): bool {
        $program = $this
            ->em
            ->getRepository(FileUpload::class)->find($countryCode);
        if ($program->getCountryCode() != null) {
            $program->setFileData($program->getFileData());
            $this->em->persist($program);
            return true;
        }
        $program1 = new FileUpload($countryCode, $fileData);

        $this->em->persist($program1);
        $this->em->flush();


        return true;
    }
```

But now it is throwing error.

```
Call to a member function getCountryCode() on null (500 Internal Server Error)
```

I am not able to understand the issue. Could you please help me on the same.

`Edit 1` :-

```
  /**
     * @param string $countryCode,
     * @param string $fileData
     */
    public function fileUpload(
        string $countryCode,
        string $fileData

    ): bool {
        $program = $this->em->getRepository(FileUpload::class)->findByCountryCode($countryCode);
        if ($program != null) {
            $program->setFileData($fileData);
            $this->em->persist($program);
            return true;
        }
        $program1 = new FileUpload($countryCode, $fileData);

        $this->em->persist($program1);
        $this->em->flush();


        return true;
    }
```

I changed the code now getting below error.

```
Call to a member function setFileData() on array (500 Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: The `find` methods finds a record _by its primary key_, you are passing another field completely, what you want is `findOneByCountryCode` (assuming entries are unique, `findByCountryCode` otherwise, but that returns an array).

Comment: Try with findBy, it returns an array: $this->em->getRepository(FileUpload::class)->findBy(array('countryCode' => $countryCode);

Comment: I am getting error after modifying the code. I have edited the code.

Comment: As I said, `findByCountryCode` returns an array. You have to loop through the results inside the `if`. And you probably want to put the `$program1` stuff inside an `else` block, otherwise you are creating a new element even if it exists.

Comment: its working now. thanks a lot @msg

Comment: Somebody did mass downvoting on my questions. now I am not able to ask any question. stackoverflow blocked me :(